# .Net create and open doc using openxml

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How can one create and open document using .net(c#)?

Here is the code:

```
    String docName = "ThisIsATesterDoc";
using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(docName,WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)){
          package.AddMainDocumentPart();
          package.MainDocumentPart.Document =
          new Document(
              new Body(
                  new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(
                      new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(
                          new Text("Hello World")))));
         package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this code work? What is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't believe it's saving a document. Or am I missing something?